# when UIsearchController searchbar become active there is a gap showing in the place of statusbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

In my `UIViewController` One `UITableView`  showing list of items, I added `UISearchController` in the `UIViewController` not in `UITableView.tableHeader`. and add another result `UITableViewController` for showing the results. And added the property `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation=yes;` 
to `UISearchController`.
 But my problem is when I start to search the There is a gap between `UISearchController` and the top of the screen, `UISearchController` is not expanding the height. My `UISearchController.searchBar` is like this [image]

but I need like the image given below
[image]

Could you please Help me,
Thank you.

Comment: Change your status bar background color with your UisearchbarController background color your problem solve

Comment: I used custom 'UINavigationBar' and also used     '[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];'   for coming 'UISearchController.searchBar' below the 'NavigationBar'